# Resize logo in navbar header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a logo inside a navbar-header like this:

```
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <span><a class="navbar-brand toplogo" href="#"><img src="img/beta.png"/></a></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sign up!</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <div>
        </nav
```

My CSS is here:

```
.toplogo {

    height : 30%;
    width : 30%;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

I tried many different combinations in .toplogo, but the image size never changes. I tried cascading `.navbar-brand .toplogo`, but that didn't work either. Does anyone know how I can resize the logo in the header? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you want to change the size of img in logo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the image to resize like you want it, you have to target `.toplogo img` and not just `toplogo`.

Your CSS should look like this:

```
.toplogo {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.toplogo img {
    height : 30%;
    width : 30%;
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lp9hz157/).

Answer (score 1):

put the .toplogo in the `<img>` tags

```
<img class="toplogo" src="img/beta.png"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to do it

1. Either change in css file

```
.toplogo img {
    height : 30%;
    width : 30%;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

2. Or put class with img tag

```
<img class="toplogo" src="img/beta.png"/>
```